# How to maintain centralized logging for all jobs in oozie

Tags: hadoop, logging, hdfs, oozie

Can we configure centralized logging for all actions in Oozie. Log repository can be on either local machine or HDFS. Are there any opensource components to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Probably a logger who emits records over network would help you when you've control over your action e.g. Shell while hive/pig/etc.. actions logging is done by HDP framework